# Error with installing Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with installing Rails 4. Hope you could help!

demo

```
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

demo

```
$ sudo gem install rails

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
        Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution for installing Rails is by Using Ruby Version Manager(**RVM**)

run `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` to install RVM and the Install Ruby Using RVM by this Command `rvm install 2.0.0` then Install Rails from this command

`gem install rails -v 4.0.0`

You can good to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and everything is described here: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

**tl;dr** Recent versions of RVM, the Ruby Version Manager, include a utility to diagnose and resolve errors caused by outdated certificate files. See the article Installing Rails for instructions and advice. The RVM website explains how to install RVM.

If you’ve installed RVM, try this:

```
$ rvm -v
# rvm 1.19.1 (stable)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
# Certificates for...
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
# Updating certificates...
```

That’s all that is needed to resolve the issue if you are using RVM (you must be using RVM version 1.19.1 or newer).